# word meaning : Large ( in terms of money)

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across this in The Mentalist-S03E04. The guy says

"I was looking for my money. He owes me 22 large, plus nine years interest."

What does large mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of US dollars, **"large" means a multiple of $1000**. Twenty-two large means twenty-two thousand dollars.

There are [many such terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money), including "grand", "big ones", "monkeys", and more.

Comment: See also "grand", very common in British and American English for one thousand pounds or dollars, also "big ones" "fat ones", etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've now linked to a long list.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - True, although some of those terms are more common than others, and some are more mainstream than others. It wouldn't surprise me at all if my dad told me he spent "twenty-two grand" on his new pickup truck, but I'd be very surprised if he said, "22 large" or "22 fat ones" or "22 monkeys". Some of those slang terms wouldn't seem so out of place on a crime drama, though.

Comment: Context and situation supplies meaning. If I said "I paid fifteen for my Beemer, with a new clutch thrown in", I would expect my listener to understand exactly what I meant.